# Hybrid meta box, how to show?

Tags: metabox

As a designer I'm not that well in PHP. I've created a (hybrid) meta box. Now I want to show the meta stuff on my template. For some reason I can't get it hooked in my template.

The meta box is saving stuff propperly.

```
function hybrid_service_meta_boxes() {

/* Array of the meta box options. */
$meta_boxes = array(
    'doc' => array( 'name' => 'doc', 'title' => __('doc', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'text' ),
    'description' => array( 'name' => 'Description', 'title' => __('Description', 'hybrid'), 'type' => 'textarea' ),            
);

return apply_filters( 'hybrid_service_meta_boxes', $meta_boxes );}
```

The problem now is, how do I hook this up to the front?

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Service', true) ) : ?>

Test succes

<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see I'm testing if the stuff is working, but I won't get the 'test succes'.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I think 'Service' is incorrect..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'doc', true ) ?>
```

'doc' fetches one of meta_boxes array items. Then you can echo them

And.. check if you are editing the right single.php (my mistake).